# How do I install the latest version of Sphinx Seach in Apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, apt, aptitude, sphinxsearch

When I do "sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch", I get version 0.9.  I want the latest stable version (which is 2.4, I believe)

How can I do that using aptitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a third party repository, or else upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.  The 12.04 repositories contain [sphinxsearch 2.0.4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/sphinxsearch), which is [current](http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/) as of March 2012.

Comment: How do I upgrade my ubuntu to 12.04? I'm on 11. Welcome to Ubuntu 11.10 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-14-virtual x86_64)

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade`.  Back your system up first.

Answer (score 3):

You can just download the source files and compile it.  Its a very straightforward compile and takes just a couple minutes.  From the site (http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#installing):

**2.3. Installing Sphinx on Linux**

Extract everything from the distribution tarball (haven't you already?) and go to the sphinx subdirectory. (We are using version 2.0.1-beta here for the sake of example only; be sure to change this to a specific version you're using.)

```
$ tar xzvf sphinx-2.0.1-beta.tar.gz
$ cd sphinx
```

Run the configuration program:

```
$ ./configure
```

There's a number of options to configure. The complete listing may be obtained by using --help switch. The most important ones are:

--prefix, which specifies where to install Sphinx; such as --prefix=/usr/local/sphinx (all of the examples use this prefix)

--with-mysql, which specifies where to look for MySQL include and library files, if auto-detection fails;

--with-pgsql, which specifies where to look for PostgreSQL include and library files.

Build the binaries:

```
$ make
```

Install the binaries in the directory of your choice: (defaults to /usr/local/bin/ on *nix systems, but is overridden with configure --prefix)

```
$ make install
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the repository from ppa:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:dhuggins/cmusphinx
apt-get update 
apt-get install  sphinxsearch
```

Comment: This worked for me.But i used update instead of install

Answer (score -2):

Install sphinx search on any ubuntu version.

1. go to synaptic package manager
2. search for `sphinxsearch`, then select it and install.
3. after installation sphinx config files are located in `/etc/sphinxsearch/` folder.
4. open command propt
5. `$sudo gedit /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf`
6. open file and change as per your requirnment.
7. If the file is empty, you must create it using this command: `$sudo cp /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf.sample /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf`
8. issue the command `sudo indexer --rotate --all` and your indexing will start.

Comment: Please note that your answer does not pertain on the point that the OP's apt sources do not seem to include the desired version of the software.